# Is the ray model appropriate only for spherical/planar waves?

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics

In ray optics, light propagation is modeled using rays, i.e., curves that are perpendicular to the wavefront. In general, rays can be curved; however, if the medium is homogeneous, it follows that the rays are straight lines. In my understanding, this is a consequence from Maxwell's equations in the case when the wavelength is negligible.

I am not sure if the ray model can be used to model the propagation of waves that are not planar or spherical, especially if the "shape" of the wavefront changes. For example, a Gaussian beam behaves initially as a plane wave but asymptotically as a spherical wave. I don't see how straight rays can be applied in such cases if the medium is homogeneous. Is it caused by some assumption in the general ray model (=energy is transported along curves perpendicular to the wavefront) that the shape of the wavefront must be preserved, i.e., every "point" on the wavefront propagates/expands with the same speed (as in the case of plane/spherical waves)?

Answer (score 2):

The rays of geometric optics are one dimensional and have no structure. They cannot be used to study the propagation of light in general. The theory of diffraction is needed to analyse the propagation of light in the most general case.